# Asymptotic of Inverse Function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, asymptotics

Suppose we choose a positive constant $c$ and let $f_c(x)=\frac12x^2+cx^{3/2}$. I would like to get an asymptotic estimate for the function $f_c^{-1}(x)$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. I assume it will be something of the form $f_c^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{2x}+O(g_c(x))$ for some function $g_c(x)$ of order less than $\sqrt x$, but I'm not sure how to get a nice estimate for $g_c(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

I can propose this method. Let
$$
y = \frac{x^2}{2} + cx^{3/2}.
$$
$y$ is strictly increasing (when $c\ge0$), so inverse function exists. And we have $y\to\infty$ when $x\to\infty$. $x^{3/2}=o(x^2)$, and you start correctly:
$$
x\sim\sqrt{2y}.
$$
Next step:
$$
x\sim\sqrt{2y}(1+z(y)),
$$
where $z(y) = o(1)$. Put back:
$$
y = y(1+z)^2 + c(2y)^{3/4}(1+z)^{3/2},
$$
or
$$
y(2z+z^2) + c(2y)^{3/4}(1+z)^{3/2} = 0.
$$
Since $z=o(1)$, we can write
$$
y\cdot 2z + c(2y)^{3/4}\left(1+\frac32z\right) = 0,
$$
and
$$
z = -\frac{2c}{3c+2(2y)^{1/4}}.
$$
Hence
$$
x\sim \sqrt{2y}\left(1 -\frac{2c}{3c+2(2y)^{1/4}}\right)
$$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the equation $$F=\frac12x^2+cx^{3/2}-y$$ and use the first iteration of Newton method starting at $x_0=\sqrt{2y}$. What is obtained is $$x_1=\sqrt{2y}\Big(1-\frac{2 c}{3 c+2 \sqrt[4]{2y} }\Big)$$ which is looking quite close to Michael Galuza's answer.

The same could be done using Halley method but the result would be much more complex.

For illustration purposes, let us use $c=10$, $y=10^{10}$; the approximation leads to $x=137805.$ while the solution is $x=137758.$

**Edit**

We can also do other things such as applying Newton method a few times to update the solution and then expand the result as a Taylor series for infinitely large values of $y$. It seems that the expansion tends to converge to $$x=(2y)^{1/2}-c(2y)^{1/4}+c^2-\frac {7 c^3}8(2y)^{-1/4}+\frac {5 c^4}8(2y)^{-1/2}-\frac{39 c^5}{128}(2y)^{-3/4}+\cdots$$ which, for the example, gives $137758.4700$ which is the solution for $10$ significant figures.

We also could build the simplest Pade approximant at $x=\sqrt{2y}$ and solve. This would lead to $$x=\frac{3 c^2 \sqrt{z}+12 c z^{3/4}+8 z}{15 c^2+20 c \sqrt[4]{z}+8 \sqrt{z}}$$ where $z=2y$.

**Edit**

The problem looked worth for generalization considering the equation $$F=ax^m+b x^n-y$$ where $m>n>0$, $a>0,b>0$ and infinitely large values of $y$.

Defining $$x=z \left(\frac{y}{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{m}}$$ $$\alpha=\frac{b }{y}\left(\frac{y}{a}\right)^{\frac{n}{m}}$$ the equation reduces to $$F=z^m+\alpha z^n-1$$ Using $z_0=1$, repeating Newton iterations for a few times and expanding the result as Taylor series built at $\alpha=0$ gives the following asymptotics $$z=1-\frac{\alpha }{m}+\frac{\alpha ^2 (-m+2 n+1)}{2 m^2}+\frac{\alpha ^3 \left(-2 m^2+9
   m n+3 m-9 n^2-6 n-1\right)}{6 m^3}+O\left(\alpha ^4\right)$$

Comment: Thought I'd add a link to the [Kantorovich Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kantorovich_theorem) which can be used to generate effective bounds on Newton approximants, under some assumptions.

Comment: @MikeF. This is indeed a good point ! Why don't you post an answer ? It would be very interesting. Thanks and Cheers.

Comment: The only difference between the solutions is that the denominator of the fraction here is $3c+2\sqrt[4]{2y}$, whereas it is $3c+2\sqrt[4]{2}y$ in Michael Galuza's solution. However, if you work through the details, I believe his solution just has a typo and should actually be identical to the one you have here.

Comment: You may be right concerning a possible typo. Anyway, I added some stuff to my answer.

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici : Could you explain  how the simplest Pade approximant was found in detail?

Comment: For a function $f(x)$, the simplest Pade approximant (degree 1 for both numerator and denominator) built at $x=a$ is given by $$\frac{\frac{(x-a) \left(2 f'(a)^2-f(a) f''(a)\right)}{2 f'(a)}+f(a)}{1-\frac{(x-a)
   f''(a)}{2 f'(a)}}$$

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici : This also is mechanized in Maple.

Comment: @ColinDefant, I edited my post, I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

From
$f(x)
=\frac12x^2+cx^{3/2}
=\frac12 x^{2}(1 +2cx^{-1/2})
$,
$\sqrt{f(x)}
=\sqrt{\frac12} x(1 +2cx^{-1/2})^{1/2}
=\sqrt{\frac12} x(1 +cx^{-1/2}+O(1/x))
$.
Therefore
$x 
=\sqrt{2 f(x)}(1 +2cx^{-1/2})^{-1/2}
=\sqrt{2 f(x)}(1 +O(x^{-1/2}))
\approx\sqrt{2 f(x)}
$.

Putting this back in,

$\begin{array}\\
x 
&\approx\sqrt{2 f(x)}(1 +2c\left(\sqrt{2 f(x)}\right)^{-1/2})^{-1/2}\\
&=\sqrt{2 f(x)}(1 +d(f(x))^{-1/4})^{-1/2}
\quad\text{(where } d=c\sqrt{2})\\
&\approx\sqrt{2 f(x)}(1 +(-1/2)d(f(x))^{-1/4}+\frac{(-1/2)(-3/2)}{2}d^2(f(x))^{-1/2}+O(f(x)^{-3/4}))\\
&=\sqrt{2 f(x)} -\frac{d}{\sqrt{2}}(f(x))^{1/4}+\frac{3d^2}{8}+O(f(x)^{-1/4}))\\
&=\sqrt{2 f(x)} -c(f(x))^{1/4}+\frac{3c^2}{4}+O(f(x)^{-1/4}))
\end{array}
$

Anyway,
something like this
should be true.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the solution possesses an asymptotic expansion of the form
$$
x \sim \sqrt {2y} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{a_k (c)}}{{(2y)^{k/4} }}} ,\quad y\to+\infty,
$$
with $a_0 (c) = 1$, we find
$$
y = \frac{{x^2 }}{2} + cx^{3/2} \sim y\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{j = 0}^k {a_j (c)a_{k - j} (c)} } \right)\!\frac{1}{{(2y)^{k/4} }}}  + c(2y)^{3/4} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\mathsf{A}_{3/2,k} (a_1 (c), \ldots ,a_k (c))}}{{(2y)^{k/4} }}} .
$$
Here the $\mathsf{A}_{\rho,k}$ denote the ordinary potential polynomials. They may be defined in terms of the [ordinary Bell polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Ordinary_Bell_polynomials):
$$
\mathsf{A}_{\rho ,k} (x_1 , \ldots ,x_k ) = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^k {\binom{\rho}{j}\widehat{B}_{k,j} (x_1 , \ldots ,x_{k - j + 1} )} .
$$
After simplification,
$$
0 \sim \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left( {2c\,\mathsf{A}_{3/2,k - 1} (a_1 (c), \ldots ,a_{k - 1} (c)) + \sum\limits_{j = 0}^k {a_j (c)a_{k - j} (c)} } \right)\!\frac{1}{{(2y)^{k/4} }}} ,
$$
which implies the recurrence relation
$$
a_k (c) =  - c\,\mathsf{A}_{3/2,k - 1} (a_1 (c), \ldots ,a_{k - 1} (c)) - \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{k - 1} {a_j (c)a_{k - j} (c)}.
$$
In particular, $a_1 (c) = - c$ and
$$
a_2 (c) =  - c\,\mathsf{A}_{3/2,1} (a_1 (c)) - \frac{1}{2}a_1^2 (c) =  - c\frac{3}{2}a_1 (c) - \frac{1}{2}a_1^2 (c) = c^2 .
$$
This is in agreement with the result given in the answer by Claude Leibovici.